# Unable to connect to SQL Server LocalDB using TypeORM

Tags: node.js, sql-server, nestjs, typeorm, localdb

I am trying to connect to my SQL Server LocalDB using TypeORM from nodejs.

My TypeORM config looks like this:

```
import { DataSourceOptions, DataSource } from 'typeorm';

export const dataSourceOptions: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: 'mssql',
  host: '(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB',
  database: 'TestDb',
  synchronize: false,
  logging: true,
  options: {
    trustServerCertificate: true,
  },
  entities: ['dist/persistence/entities/*.entity{ .ts,.js}'],
  migrations: ['dist/persistence/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
  migrationsTableName: '_DbMigrations',
  migrationsRun: true,
};

const dataSource = new DataSource(dataSourceOptions);
export default dataSource;
```

But on starting nodejs, I am getting this error:

> [Nest] 37892  - 03/09/2024, 10:33:30 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)...
> ConnectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND (localdb)

Comment: LocalDB connections require the Named Pipes protocol. The [tedious driver](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious) under [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) only supports the TCP/IP protocol so, as far as I know, it's not possible to connect to LocalDB instances from Javascript. e.g.: [Does tedious support localdb? #348](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/348)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (localdb) syntax is not a valid hostname for connecting to a SQL Server LocalDB instance. Instead, you should use the actual machine name or IP address where your LocalDB instance is running.
If you’re running LocalDB on the same machine where your Node.js application is running, you can use localhost or 127.0.0.1 as the host.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).